# Sync Loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to automate a task using Javascript. I read a text file and the string in each line must go in a text input located inside a modal. To open this modal, I need to click a button.

The problem with my code is, the last line of the text file is pasted into the text input... obviously because the for loop does not wait for the other instructions to complete before iterating.

```
for (i=0; i <= rules.length; i++) {
    console.log(rules[i]);
    btn_new_segment.click();
    txt_segment_name.value = rules[i]['name'];
    btn_save_segment.click();
}
```

The `console.log(rules[i]);` prints the content of the array correctly. How can I force the FOR loop to wait until the `btn_save_segment.click();` is completed before iterating the next item in the array?

Comment: More code could be helpful. But it sounds like you could just save all the text to vars and then *after* the loop is finished put it all in the text fields in your modal.

Comment: This depends on the contents of `btn_new_segment.click();` and `btn_save_segment.click();`. The for loop will *always* wait for the other instructions to complete before iterating. But if the click does some asynchronous action, then you'll just be scheduling a number of actions with the loop and it will likely "save" only the last one.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's 2 years late but it might help others

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,'onPassLast',{
    get: function(){this.onPassLastFN(this)},
    set: function(fn){this.onPassLastFN=fn;}
}); 
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,'loop',{
    set: function(cb){
        if(typeof cb == "function"){this.callBack=cb;}else{this.currentIndex=this.currentIndex+cb;};
        this.currentIndex=this.currentIndex==undefined?0:this.currentIndex;
        if(this.currentIndex>=this.length){
            return this.onPassLast;
        }else{
            this.callBack!=undefined?this.callBack(this[this.currentIndex],this):false;
        };      
    }
});
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,'next',{
    get: function(){this.loop=1;}
});
```

It is now possible to step through each array synchronously

In your case the code would look something like this:

```
rules.onPassLast=function(){
  console.log("The loop is complete")
}
rules.loop=function(element,arr){
  console.log(element);
  btn_new_segment.click();
  txt_segment_name.value = element['name'];
  btn_save_segment.click();
}
var btn_save_segment.onclick=function(){
   //... Your code ...
  rules.next;
}
```

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,'onPassLast',{
    get: function(){this.onPassLastFN(this)},
    set: function(fn){this.onPassLastFN=fn;}
}); 
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,'loop',{
    set: function(cb){
        if(typeof cb == "function"){this.callBack=cb;}else{this.currentIndex=this.currentIndex+cb;};
        this.currentIndex=this.currentIndex==undefined?0:this.currentIndex;
        if(this.currentIndex>=this.length){
            return this.onPassLast;
        }else{
            this.callBack!=undefined?this.callBack(this[this.currentIndex],this):false;
        };      
    }
});
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,'next',{
    get: function(){this.loop=1;}
});

let rules=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
rules.onPassLast=function(){
  console.log("FINISH!");//the function is executed at the end of the loop, after all iterations
}
rules.loop=function(element,arr){
  console.log(element);//display the current array element
  arr.next;//initiate a jump to the next element in the array
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From your code, it seems you have the content in `rules` already, and `txt_segment_name` is the `text input located inside a modal` you said. 
If so, the `for` loop CAN set the value of the every element in `rules` to `txt_segment_name` instantly, but the `txt_segment_name` WILL NOT BE REPRESENTED UNTIL THE END OF ENTIRE JS CODE EXECUTING. so that's why you just saw the value of the last element of `rules`.

You can use a timer/interval to implement it. Like

```
let currentIndex = 0;
let interval = setInterval(()=>{
    btn_new_segment.click();
    txt_segment_name.value = rules[currentIndex]['name'];
    btn_save_segment.click();
    currentIndex ++;
    if (currentIndex >= rules.length) {
       clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 200);
```

Then you can see the value of the array changed in the input every 200ms. I do not know very much about `btn_new_segment` and `btn_save_segment`. You may need to change the code for them.

Comment: Can anybody leave a comment if you do not agree my answer, please?